# Migrate posts into a different category

Tags: categories

I have about 1500 posts I want to change category for.

Is there a quick way to do this in Wordpress Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No quick way exists in the WordPress admin for 1500 posts, the better way would be to do it with MySQL directly either by custom queries and updated or by PhpMyAdmin and his friends.

Comment: +1 @ bainternet, but before you actually run the query do two things.. **1)** back up database (obvious but you would be amazed how many people dont) and finally **2)** always run a SELECT query as a test before running the actual UPDATE query

Comment: @Martin: The only problem with this is that all my posts have a post_category of 0 in PHPMyAdmin, even though in WP they display in different categories.  There is no obvious wp_categories table either.

Comment: Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description